# How to make a button pattern?

Tags: html, button

I'm trying to make a little puzzle game in HTML5 and I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a puzzle. In the puzzle you have to click the squares in a certain order to beat it. I don't know how to make it to where you have to click the buttons in order and if you don't you'll lose.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Room Two</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="youtubeGame.css">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine|Inconsolata|Droid+Sans|Oxygen|Ubuntu|Coming+Soon">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h1 id="roomNum">Room 2</h1>
            <p id="roomInfo">Once again the door seems to magically close behind 
you.<br /> Unlike the stone floor from the previous room, this one is divided up 
into wooden slabs.<br /> You press your foot onto a slab. It slides down, and an 
arrrow shoots from the roof.<br /> You barely get out of the way but somehow you 
dodge it. You tell yourself to watch your step...</p>

            <p id="step"></p>

            <p id="step2"></p>

            <div class="menu-container" id="puzzle">
                <div class="button-container">
                 <a href="#" class="button" onclick="wrongStep()">1</a>
                 <a href="#" class="button" onclick="correctStep6()">2</a>
                 <a href="#" class="button" onclick="correctStep7()">3</a>
                 <a href="#" class="button" onclick="wrongStep()">4</a>
                 <a href="#" class="button" onclick="correctStep5()">5</a>
                 <a href="#" class="button" onclick="correctStep4()">6</a>
                 <a href="#" class="button" onclick="correctStep1()">7</a>
                 <a href="#" class="button" onclick="correctStep2()">8</a>
                 <a href="#" class="button" onclick="correctStep3()">9</a>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br><br>

        <div id="death">
            <a href="youtubeGame.html">Try Again?</a>
        </div>

        <a href="roomThree.html" id="nextRoom">Next Room</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            document.getElementById("death").style.display = "none";

            document.getElementById("nextRoom").style.display = "none";

            function correctStep1() {
                return true;    
            }
            function correctStep2() {
                return true;
            }

            function correctStep3() {
                return true;
            }

            function correctStep4() {
                return true;
            }

            function correctStep5() {
                return true;
            }

            function correctStep6() {
                return true;
            }

            function correctStep7() {
                return true;
            }

            function wrongStep() {
                document.getElementById("content").style.display = "none;"

                document.getElementById("puzzle").style.display = "none";

                document.getElementById("death").style.display = "block";

                document.getElementById("roomNum").innerHTML = "You Have 
Died";

                document.getElementById("roomInfo").style.display = "none";
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way would be to save the correct order in an array and if the user clicks, increment a clickcounter and check if the clicked button is at this position in the array:

```
var state = {
  clickedButtons:[]
};
var correctClickSettings = {
  order:[7,8,9,6,5,2,3],
  resetOn:7 // order has 7 elements, so the user have to click 7 buttons, after that it will be checked and the clicked buttons will be resolved or rejected
};
// called from every button that can be clicked to solve the game
function onClick(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var sourceButtonText = this.innerText;
  state.clickedButtons.push(sourceButtonText);
  if(state.clickedButtons.length >= correctClickSettings.resetOn) {
    var distanceBetweenArrays = state.clickedButtons.reduce((cur,val,idx)=>cur+Math.abs(val-correctClickSettings.order[idx]),0);
    if(distanceBetweenArrays > 0) {
      wrongStep();
      state.clickedButtons = [];
    } else {
      alert('This was right!');
    }
  }
}
```

This solution has one problem: Everybody with a little bit of understanding for javascript can open the webpage and read out the solution. So if you want to do it a little better (not so easaly cheatable) you have to use another solution:

You can use a hash instead of an array of button clicks as correct order:

```
function simpleHash(currentHash, idx, sourceButtonText) {
  currentHash = currentHash*137+parseInt(sourceButtonText,10);
}
```

Now simply calculate the correct solution value: 46672273550408 (in your case)

Now with every button click calculate the next hash and compare it after 7 steps with the solution.

Comment: How would I implement this into my script? Like where would I put this and what would I change. I'm not super good at this :P It's looks good though

Comment: @JaydenWyatt Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cajoqaue/

Comment: Actually I found something wrong. What your program does is take in 7 answer then decide if its correct or not. how do i fix that?

Comment: @JaydenWyatt It's realy simple, right? If you have any problems, just write a comment. There is no need to change your markup :) It works out of the box. || EDIT: Don't forget to select an answer if your question is successfully answered :)

Comment: Yeah it is surprisingly simple. Thanks for your help. I love the stack overflow community. Hopefully one day I'll be this good

Comment: Also, I've been wanting to get a kind of tester for the game to help test, give ideas, and fix the code. Would you happen to someone i could contact or even yourself do that? It's not easy finding all the answers for the code I want fixed

Comment: @JaydenWyatt and as an addon the obfuscated solution: https://jsfiddle.net/cajoqaue/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar approach to your current implementation, however uses attributes to declare the order of the options. It also does the binding of the events directly through javascript.

```js
var options = [];
var expected = 0; 

document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach((button, index)=>{
  options.push({
    button: button,
    order: button.getAttribute('order'),
    index: index,
    clicked: false
  });
  
  button.addEventListener('click',onClick);
  
  //console.log(options[options.length-1]);
});

function onClick(event){
   let order = parseInt(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('order'));

   if(order == expected){
    expected++;
    options[order].clicked = true;
    console.log(options[order]);
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 id="roomNum">Room 2</h1>
  <p id="roomInfo">Once again the door seems to magically close behind you.
    <br /> Unlike the stone floor from the previous room, this one is divided up into wooden slabs.<br /> You press your foot onto a slab. It slides down, and an arrrow shoots from the roof.<br /> You barely get out of the way but somehow you dodge it.
    You tell yourself to watch your step...</p>

  <p id="step"></p>

  <p id="step2"></p>

  <div class="menu-container" id="puzzle">
    <div class="button-container">
      <a href="#" class="button" order="7">1</a>
      <a href="#" class="button" order="8">2</a>
      <a href="#" class="button" order="9">3</a>
      <a href="#" class="button" order="6">4</a>
      <a href="#" class="button" order="5">5</a>
      <a href="#" class="button" order="0">6</a>
      <a href="#" class="button" order="3">7</a>
      <a href="#" class="button" order="2">8</a>
      <a href="#" class="button" order="1">9</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div id="death">
  <a href="youtubeGame.html">Try Again?</a>
</div>

<a href="roomThree.html" id="nextRoom">Next Room</a>
```

Comment: how could I set it to the correct pattern? It's 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 2, 3

Comment: @JaydenWyatt you just have to change the order attribute - I will update my example.